# Should postcss plugins reference postcss as a peer dependency?

Tags: javascript, css, npm, sass, postcss

I'm attempting to use the [PostCSS Sass Color Function](https://github.com/adam-h/postcss-sass-color-functions).  I get this error:

```
    Unknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 6.0.22, but postcss-sass-color-functions uses 5.2.18. Perhaps this is the source of the error below.
    (node:12911) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /home/ole/Junk/superflycss/component-button/node_modules/@superflycss/variables-colors/notifications/index.css:76:9: Unable to parse color from string "25%"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Postcss-sass-color-functions](https://github.com/adam-h/postcss-sass-color-functions#----no-longer-maintained----) is no longer maintained as mentioned in their repository.

You can use [postcss-preset-env](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env) instead with `color-mod-function` enabled to do the same.